# html5 deleting a text and adding a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Based on user input data in a text box, I append the data in a section (with a border) in html like below:

```
<section class="borderexample" id="data_zone">

</section>




<script>
var gotName = localStorage.getItem("storageName");
$('#data_zone').prepend('<p><strong>' + gotName + '</strong></p>');
</script>
```

Now, when I have another user input, I want to erase the previous data and just put the new data. How do I do that? Doing only .prepend will keep adding, will not erase previous data.

Suggestion?

Comment: `.prepend()` doesn't append, it prepends. `.append()` appends. And `.html()` replaces.

Comment: "append" means to add at the end, "prepend" means to add at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try doing:

```
document.querySelector('#data_zone').innerHTML = 'something';
```

Or with jQuery

```
$('#data_zone').html('something');
```

This, will erase all the HTML in the Element and replace it with `something`

Hope I helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try erasing the content of desired element first:

```
$('#data_zone').html('');
```